# Android Device Monitor Data does not seem

Tags: android, device, android-device-monitor

I want to see my all records in my database, but when i go file explorer data file seems bu it is not opening. What is the reason of that can u please help me?[here this is the screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00RrH.jpg)

Comment: which explorer you using to open it?

Comment: Have i to use mozilla fireworks? I am sorry because i am 2 months experienced on Android.

Answer (score 0):

read here all the [explorer](https://fileinfo.com/extension/prop) you can use to open .prop file

Comment: Thanks but i only want to see my database. :/

Comment: that means you want to open default.prop isn't it?

Comment: Most of tutorial says that file.db in data file on device.

Comment: I cannot see file.db in the screenshot

Comment: Becase i cant open the data file. :)